# Check an input of type "checkbox" if its value is equal to an array member?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to tick boxes that have the same value as an array item. I can't figure out how to get only the matching input to be checked. It's usually all or nothing.

#### JS

```
var arr = 'Comedy, Sports, Psychological'.split(', ');

function inputShouldBeChecked() {
    $.each(arr, function (index, value) {
        if ( value.toLowerCase() === $('#genre input[type=checkbox]').val().toLowerCase() ) {
            // it's not possible to get the input as a $(this), is it?
            $('#genre input[value='+ value +']').prop('checked', true); //???
        }
    });
}
$('button').click(inputShouldBeChecked);
```

#### HTML

```
<button>Check Genre</button>
<ul id="genre">
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="genre-name" value="Sports" />
        Sports
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="genre-name" value="Comedy" />
        Comedy
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="genre-name" value="Action" />
        Action
    </li>
</ul>
```

Am I making this harder than it needs to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it:

```
var arr = 'Comedy, Sports, Psychological'.split(', ');  
function inputShouldBeChecked() {
    $.each(arr, function (index, value) {          
        $("#genre input[value="+value+"]").prop("checked",true)
    });
}
$('button').click(inputShouldBeChecked);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/TZQnS/233/)**

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the following if condition, just remove it.

```
if ( value.toLowerCase() === $('#genre input[type=checkbox]').val().toLowerCase() )
```

```js
$(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
  var arr = 'Comedy, Sports, Psychological'.split(', ');

  function inputShouldBeChecked() {
    $.each(arr, function(index, value) {
      $('#genre input[value=' + value + ']').prop('checked', true);
    });
  }
  $('button').click(inputShouldBeChecked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Check Genre</button>
<ul id="genre">
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="genre-name" value="Sports" />Sports
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="genre-name" value="Comedy" />Comedy
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="genre-name" value="Action" />Action
  </li>
</ul>
```